# Is it possible to endlessly add key:value pairs to a dictionary based upon user input?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, input

I have a dictionary called "user_database" that holds users, and a variable called "registered_users" that increments as the input is called in a "while True" loop. How can I endlessly add new users to the dictionary as the inputs are entered?
this is what I have, (BTW I am a beginner at python)

```
user_database = {
    "username": "my_username",
    "password": "my_password"
}
 
registered_users = 1

def register_user(user_database):
    if user_database:
        while True:
            for i in range(3):
                registered_users = i += 1
                username = input("Enter your username: ")
                password = input("Enter your password: ")
                user_database[f'username_{registered_users}'] = username
                user_database[f'password_{registered_users}'] = password
                print(user_database)
                continue
register_user(user_database)
```

here is the output:

```
Enter your username: sunshine
Enter your password: sunshine123
{'username': 'my_username', 'password': 'my_password', 'username_1': 'sunshine', 'password_1': 'sunshine123'}
Enter your username: sunshine_2
Enter your password: sunshine555
{'username': 'my_username', 'password': 'my_password', 'username_1': 'sunshine_2', 'password_1': 'sunshine555'}
Enter your username:
```

It is not adding A NEW key:value pair on EACH entry, its simply replacing the extra one.
I want to add a new key:pair upon each username & password input entry.

I have tried update() and It did the same thing. Although I may have used it incorrectly.

Comment: `registered_users = i += 1` doesn't make any sense. Perhaps you just want `registered_users += 1` or just skip the use of `registered_users` entirely and just use `i`, e.g. `user_database[f'username_{i}'] = username`

Comment: If I change it to registered_users += 1 it gives me a value error for some reason..but I took it out completely and put this instead and it works!! Thank you.

Comment: Don't put "SOLVED" in the title. Instead, either close/remove the question if you no longer need an answer, or accept a correct answer to your original question (and revert the title to the original).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would do what you would want:

```py
user_database = [{
    "username": "my_username",
    "password": "my_password"
}]
 
registered_users = 1

def register_user(user_database):
    global registered_users
    if user_database:
        while True:
            registered_users += 1
            new_user = {}

            username = input("Enter your username: ")
            password = input("Enter your password: ")
            new_user[f'username_{registered_users}'] = username
            new_user[f'password_{registered_users}'] = password
            user_base.append(new_user)
            
register_user(user_database)
```

In the following, the registered users are saved in a list. In this list, there are dictionaries for each user containing a key for the username and a key for the password, which is entered in the while loop. You would want to find a way to break out of the while loop yourself, otherwise you will keep going on forever. This is simply done by adding a closing condition that executes a `break`. For good measure, I have added that the variable `registered_users` is uses the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the reason using the `for` loop, but something like this will work if you are okay with the output :

```
def register_user(user_database):
    global registered_users
    if user_database:
        while True:
            registered_users += 1
            username = input("Enter your username: ")
            password = input("Enter your password: ")
            
            user_database.append({
                f'username_{registered_users}': username,
                f'password_{registered_users}': password
            })
            print(user_database)

user_database = [{
    "username": "my_username",
    "password": "my_password"
}]
 
registered_users = 1

register_user(user_database)
```

Make sure that you need to break the while using a condition or something, otherwise it will keep running forever.

The result will look like this :

```
[{'username': 'my_username', 'password': 'my_password'}, {'username_2': 'sunshine', 'password_2': 'sunshine123'}]
```

Comment: Thank you!! I really like this idea as well.

Answer (score 0):

You were going the right way. I would suggest you add usernames as your `user_database` dictionary's keys and the passwords (ideally the hashed passwords) be the dictionary's values. This way it will be really fast retrieving your existing usernames and their respective password, for authentication or other purposes you may have. I rewrote your program like this:

```
user_database = {
    'janedoe': 'MyPassword123'
}
registered_users = 1

def hash_password(password):
    hashed_password = password # do something to the password
    return hashed_password

def register_user(username, password):
    global user_database, registered_users

    if username in USERS:
        raise Exception('Can\'t use {username} as username.')

    user_database.setdefault(username, hash_password(password))
    registered_users += 1

def main():
    while True:
        username = input('What is your username? ')
        password = input('What is your password? ')

        register_user(username, password)
        print(f'Current users count: {USERS_COUNT} {USERS.keys()}')

        command = input('End program? [Y/n]')
        if command.strip().lower() in ['', 'y']:
            break
```

Just call the main function in the program, execute it, and you can start registering users.

## Hashing (A little introduction)

I know this is just a little project for you to learn, but this is just a bit of advice for you to learn even more. I hash the password using the function `hash_password` in order to make your `user_database` more secure. See [this](https://nordpass.com/blog/password-hash/) link so you can understand what is password hashing. You would have to hash every password upon users registration, the process to check for correct password would be to verify the raw password passed by users with the stored hash. There are many tutorials that show how to handle all that; it's a simple process.

Comment: This is amazing thank you!! I will definitely do more research on hashing.